# Why does the pattern *([^\/]) work in my interactive shell but not a script?

Tags: bash, string-substitution

I'm writing a script to strip a working directory to a limited length using bash parameter substitution. It works on the command line, but the same substitution does nothing in the script.

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Limit of working directory length
LIMIT=10

dir=${1/#$HOME/\~}

# If it's too long, normalize it by stripping ~ and adding ...
if [ ${#dir} -gt $LIMIT ]; then
  dir=${dir/#\~/"..."}
fi

echo $dir

# Strip levels until short enough or can't strip anymore.
while [[ ( ${#dir} -gt $LIMIT ) && ( "$dir" != "$last_dir" ) ]]; do
  last_dir="$dir"
  # Strip a level off.
  dir=${dir/#...\/*([^\/])/"..."} <- broken line
  echo $dir
done

echo $dir
```

If I do

```
test=".../School/CS352/Project1"
text=${test/#...\/*([^\/])/"..."}
```

I get `.../CS352/Project1`, which is what I want. But the same sub does nothing in my script.

**Question: How do I make the marked line in the code behave like the example above?**

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Open a shell and test the example. It's clearly not harmful and it's only two line to copypaste.

Comment: This behavior depends on whether the `extglob` shell option is set. It's off by default. Presumably your scripts are turning it on for the interactive shell.

Comment: @Kevin -- it's not regexes, but it's a comparably powerful syntax (to BREs; certainly not as expressive as PCRE). Search for "extglob" in the man page.

Comment: Do not edit answers into questions. Doing so means folks can't add other answers and have them be upvoted/downvoted on otherwise-equal footing with the accepted answer; it also means the question itself can't be upvoted/downvoted independently of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

...to turn on this support.