# Bash parameter expansion works only in interactive shell, but not in script

Tags: bash, trim

In user's console I have `bash`:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

I have code in file test.sh:

```
$ cat test.sh
aaa='---aa-aa---'
echo "${aaa}"
echo 'does not work...'
# trim "-"
echo ${aaa/+(-)}
echo ${aaa%%+(-)}
echo 'works for one symbol...'
echo ${aaa%-}
echo ${aaa/-}
```

The last two rows work fine but previous ones.

```
$ bash test.sh
---aa-aa---
does not work...
---aa-aa---
---aa-aa---
works for one symbol...
---aa-aa--
--aa-aa---
```

In the same time, if you would try to make this console it works:

```
$ aaa='---aa-aa---'
$ echo ${aaa/+(-)}
aa-aa---
$ echo ${aaa%%+(-)}
---aa-aa
```

So, why it doesn't work in a script?

Comment: Trying to decide whether to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726264/why-does-the-pattern-work-in-my-interactive-shell-but-not-a-script, or do it the other way 'round. @tripleee, do you have an opinion here?

Comment: ...actually, on review, I think this instance of the question is more clearly asked than the other, enough to negate the other's temporal advantage (from being asked first)..

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have `shopt -s extglob` enabled in your interactive shell, which turns on extended globbing. This is not the default behavior, and needs to be explicitly enabled in your script. See [extended pattern matching in the bash hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language) for details.

Comment: Without `shopt -s extglob`, the pattern `+(-)` is a literal 4-character string to match, not a pattern matching one or more `-`.